# Issue inserting data into a DB using Textarea

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Thanks for checking in.
So the issue I'm having is that everything seems perfect but somehow it still doesn't insert the values into the database.

here's the code:

```
    public function add_post($user_id,$status,$file_parh){
        global $pdo; 
        if(empty($file_parh)){
            $file_parh = 'NULL';
        }
        $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `posts` (`post_id`, `user_id_p`, `status`, `status_image`, `status_time`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?,?,  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)');
        $query->bindValue(1,$user_id);
        $query->bindValue(2,$status);
        $query->bindValue(3,$file_parh);
        $query->execute();
        header("Refresh:0");
    }
```

that's inside a file called "functions.php" which is called via another file "main.php"

it is used in another file where it uses stored data and creates some sort of "posts".

The thing is, i inserted values by myself into the database and the posts appear but there's no way I get the function to insert it.

Here's the text area:

```
<?php if($check->logged_in() === true){?>

                <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="c-header">
                        <div class="c-h-inner">
                            <ul>    
                                <li><img src="assets/images/write.png" alt="escribir" width="28" height="28"></img><a href="#">Escribir Anuncio</a></li>
                                <li><input type="file"  onchange="readURL(this);" style="display:none;" name="post_image" id="uploadFile"></li>
                                <li><img src="assets/images/imagen.png" alt="imagen" width="28" height="28"></img><a href="#" id="uploadTrigger" name="post_image">Agregar Imágen</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="c-body">
                        <div class="body-right">
                            <textarea class="publicar" name="status" placeholder="Escribí tus anuncios acá..." style="resize:vertical;border: 1px solid #ddd"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div id="body-bottom">
                        <img src="#"  id="preview"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="right-box">
                            <ul>
                                <li><input style="float:right;margin-right:5%" type="submit" name="submit" value="Publicar" class="btn2"/></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                     //Image Preview Function
                            $("#uploadTrigger").click(function(){
                               $("#uploadFile").click();
                            });
                            function readURL(input) {
                                if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                                    var reader = new FileReader();

                                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                                        $('#body-bottom').show();
                                        $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
                                    }

                                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                                }
                            }

                    </script>
```

and the insert image neither works.. sigh..

Thanks in advance!!

EDIT:

I use the add_post function here:

```
<?php
include 'core/main.php';
$check  = new Main;
$get    = new Main;
$send   = new Main;
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
//fetching user data by user_id
$data  = $get->user_data($user_id);
// fetching posts from database
$post  = $get->posts();
//check user submit  data
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $status  = $_POST['status'];
    //checking image if isset
    if (isset($_FILES['post_image'])===true) {
        //if image is not empty 
         if (empty($_FILES['post_image']['name']) ===true) {
            if(!empty($status)===true){
                $send->add_post($user_id,$status);
            }
             }else {
             //checking image format                                                                                                       
             $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); 
             $file_name = $_FILES['post_image']['name']; 
             $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
             $file_temp = $_FILES['post_image']['tmp_name'];

             if (in_array($file_extn, $allowed)===true) {
                $file_parh = 'images/posts/' . substr(md5(time()), 0, 10).'.'.$file_extn;
               move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_parh);
               $send->add_post($user_id,$status,$file_parh);

             }else{
              echo 'incorrect File only Allowed with less then 1mb ';
              echo implode(', ', $allowed);
             }
         }

    }

} ?>
```

I commented "//header("Refresh:0");" but no error happens, it simply kind of refreshes the web anyway and nothing happens.

EDIT2:
**I fixed the upload button so I can now upload images; interestingly if I upload images with a text; it does upload the image to the server but it does not save the other data into the database. Maybe a problem accesing the DB? Im kind of lost.**

Comment: PDO's `errorInfo` function

Comment: Where do you use the `add_post()` function?

Comment: Wrap those lines start with `$query` inside try catch block and then comment out last line with the header statement to see if there is any error being spat out.